# What is this Error? How do I solve this?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Mongoose warning: what is this Error? How do I solve this?

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://node:nodenode@proximus.modulusmongo.net:27017/orajY4ta');
```

> This is an UNSTABLE release of Mongoose.
>   Unstable releases are available for preview/testing only.
>   DO NOT run this in production.

Comment: what is in your package.json file

Comment: You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have to update your version of mongoose?

`npm install mongoose`